# what is ``differentiated service : congestion experienced``?

Tags: ip, wireshark, scapy

I was trying to send packets and capture them using wireshark to see how they look like using scapy

```
sr1(IP(src='192.168.1.35', dst='192.168.1.1', tos=3)/'my packet')
```

when i sent the packet and captured it in wireshark i got the full `ip` stack but this piece of the `ip` stack got my attention

```
Differentiated Services Field: 0x03 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: CE)
0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
.... ..11 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Congestion Experienced (3)]]
```

what is `Explicit Congestion Notification: Congestion Experienced` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to read RFC 3168.
TCP/IP is a complex protocol (of protocols). Your congestion notification looks to be a congestion check (ECN) implemented in your router (or source-dest path), a feature your/a router has (a good thing, an extra thing). The message you report, not necessarily has to do with your networking experiment. Can be a context issue related with overall traffic on your (intra/external) net, what usually tell systems aware, to modify speed transmissions, among other things, etc.

[ECN notifies networks about congestion with the goal of reducing packet loss and delay by making the sending device decrease the transmission rate until the congestion clears, without dropping packets. RFC 3168, The Addition of Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN) to IP, defines ECN].

Reading RFCs is a good habit.
TCP/IP is an endless deep ocean. Getting a good foundation is not easy. But try hard, there is light at the end of the tunnel.